# Rollback transaction on pressing create button and fetching the value field to insert it into the form_for

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

## ERROR

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-05 01:23:20 -0700

Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WcfuzGz2ZaEpFmagKYTm3feGTaZxNFPlTkLu/epw7fWObs+pdO4McXw9cLUNjTguav0i97rJR1sLhL5Fk+mk0g==", "product_attribute"=>{"name"=>"RAM 2355 Ghz", "size"=>"4GB", "description"=>"Its a very gooooooooood Ram"}, "value"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create"}

(0.1ms)  begin transaction

(0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Rendering products/new.html.erb within layouts/application

Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.2ms)

Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 63.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

## Description

I'm getting the above error whenever I hit the create button after filling the form.

## Products Controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @product = ProductAttribute.new
    @value = params[:value]
end

def create
    @product = ProductAttribute.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
        redirect_to statics_url
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end


private

def product_params


params.require(:product_attribute).permit(:name,:value,:size,:description)
    end
end
```

## statics Controller

```
  class StaticsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        @attributes = ProductAttribute.where(value: @product.value)
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.new(product_params)
        if @product.save
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
        if @product.update(product_params)
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

        def product_params
            params.require(:product).permit(:name,:value)
        end 
end
```

## Static view show.html.erb

```
<h1>Product listing now</h1>

<% @attributes.each do |attribute| %>
    <li><%= attribute.name%></li>
    <li><%= attribute.value%></li>
    <li><%= attribute.size%></li>
    <li><%= attribute.description%></li>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Create New Product Attributes", new_product_path(value: 
@product.value) %>
```

## Static view new.html.erb

```
<h1> New Product Creation </h1>

<%= form_for(@product, url: statics_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :value %>
    <%= f.text_field :value, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

## Product view new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add the New Product Attribute</h1>

<%= form_for(@product, url: products_path) do |f|%>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag :value, @value %>

    <%= f.label :size %>
    <%= f.text_field :size, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Create", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

## DESCRIPTION

What I'm trying to do is that, I am passing the value attribute through new_static_path(value: @product.value). I am trying to create a new Product attribute field using the existing value field (which is the primary key).
Such as example: Ram(parent field) -> (many child field with common value attributes). And I'm using the hidden_field_tag in the product's view new.html.erb so that it will be derived from controller. (I'm confused about this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try something like this:

```
def new
    @product = Product.new(value: params[:value])
end
```

This will allow Rails to put the value param inside product_attribute hash. You could also change your form value name to match the expected value

```
<input ... name="[product][value]" ... >
```

I would choose the first option, tho.

Comment: yea, finally found it out. Thanks a lot@Gil Gomes

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer by doing thorough research on stack overflow guys,

```
<%= f.hidden_field :value, :value => params[:value] %>
```

i had to specify the value using hash for options.

Thank you have a nice day.